# Joomla IP based authentication issue

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla site. there is ip based authentication based on region. when it open from isrel it identify ip of israel region and pop up for authentication for username and password. except israel region it is not required authentication. so i want to remove that security.i mean i want to remove that pop up based authentication so every user can access my site. i have try find out module for this functionality but i cant able to find out. every suggestion is accepted.thanks

Please check below screenshot.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlhmn0gy1gf6ba1/Screenshot%202015-01-08%2012.40.02.png?dl=0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "[Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)" request, generally it is set at the server level, not in the Joomla application level.

Sometimes it's configured in the `.htaccess` file (if you're using Apache) or it may be set in the servers Control Panel (e.g. `cPanel`).

If you can't find it in either of those places and haven't added a security module to your Joomla installation then I would recommend contacting your hosting provider.